# Java: using placeholders in a regex query

Tags: java, regex, placeholder

I'm writing a little program that trims everything behind a character in a file name. This character is specified by the user and I want part of my regex to adapt to that. My plan is to use a placeholder inside the regex query but I have some trouble and can't find much info about it.
This is the code I have so far:

```
//get all files (variablepath is a String passed to the method, so is altSep)
File dir = new File(path);
File[] listOfFiles = dir.listFiles();   

String regex = "[\\%s\\(\\)]+[\\w\\s]+";
regex = String.format(regex, altSep);

for (File i : listOfFiles) {
    String currName = i.getName();
    String newName = currName.replaceAll(regex, "");
    newName = path + '\\' + newName;
    File newFile = new File(newName);
    i.renameTo(newFile);
}
```

Yes, it works but also deletes everything behind a space. I'm also concerned that %s might match to other characters the user might enter. Is using placeholders in regex a good idea to begin with? (and I'm still learning Java so you might spot some other things that can be solved a lot easier)

Sidenotes: The character itself must also be deleted and since this concerns file names the extention must remain intact.

Comment: Why not `String newName = currName.substring(0, currName.indexOf(character)+1)` ?

Comment: @Grogi note that if java version <1.7, substring could have memory leak problem

Comment: @Grogi I realised I wasn't specific enough in describing the problem. Your solution is great but I also need to get rid of the given character itself. I edited my question.

Comment: The unescaped regex is `[\%s\(\)]+[\w\s]+`. Is this right? Please note here that `%` needs not be escaped.

Comment: @ccf Correct. That is the unescaped version. I removed the escape at the `%` but it still removes spaces instead of the desired character 
unfortunately

Comment: @TomKral: Then I sense the regex might not work well. Do you have any sample text?

Comment: @ccf Filenames look like this `MRSATP16R-01_S3_L001_R1.fa`. I might, for example, want to remove everything behind the underscore (underscore included)

Comment: @TomKral: So your expected result is `MRSATP16R-01.fa`, that means remove the first underscore and the rest? You are saying it deletes everything behind a space. Where is the space, in the filename?

Comment: @ccf My bad. I only posted one file name. This is another possibility: `201600 (paired) assembly.fa`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT2**  You did not post what class you use to get user input. I sense that's where the problem happens. I tried your regex with *BufferedReader* and *InputStreamReader* classes, the output is fine:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    # get filename from user
    System.out.println("Enter a filename: ");
    String currName = buffer.readLine();

    # get altSep from user
    System.out.println("Enter a altSep: ");
    String altSep = buffer.readLine(); //reader.next();
    altSep = altSep.matches("[0-9a-zA-Z]") ? altSep : "\\" + altSep;

    # format regex with user input
    String regex = "(%s.*)(?=\\.\\w+)"; 
    regex = String.format(regex, altSep);        
    String newName = currName.replaceAll(regex, "");

    # the output
    System.out.println(newName);

}
```

Output:

```
Enter a filename: 
MRS (A\ TP)1(6R)-01.fa
Enter a altSep: 
(
MRS .fa

MRS (A\ TP)1(6R)-01.fa
Enter a altSep: 
\
MRS (A.fa

MRS (A\ TP)1(6R)-01.fa
Enter a altSep: 
6
MRS (A\ TP)1(.fa

MRS (A\ TP)1(6R)-01.fa
Enter a altSep: 
P
MRS (A\ T.fa

MRS (A\ TP)1("6R")-01.fa
Enter a altSep: 
"
MRS (A\ TP)1(.fa
```

Comment: Sorry I redacted the acceptation of your answer. This answer (in particularly the regex in the comments (`(%s.*)(?=\\.\\w+)`) helped a bit but I found out it cannot accept all characters as input (like the ( character). I also edited my question a bit so you can see where input comes from

Comment: @TomKral: The reason that the regex from comments fails for input like `(` characters is that, the regex gets confused on whether it is a literal ( or capturing group start. So, I added one line to check if escape `\\` is required based on the input (altSep). Please try and see if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing regular expression 
from
    [\\%s\\(\\)]+[\\w\\s]+ 
to 
    [**\\\\%s**\\(\\)]+[\\w\\s]+

*The problem is that backslash is an escape character in both Java string literals, and regular expressions. So when you use a string literal to represent a regular expression, there are two sets of escaping to consider. And if user enters an escape character as input then the resultant regular expression may not be the desired one and may not give desired output.*